# R TTR/RSI does not behave like a Bloomberg RSI

Tags: r

The implementation of [TTR:RSI](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/TTR/docs/RSI) differs slightly from the RSI calculated in Bloomberg, see [more details here](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:relative_strength_index_rsi).

I use in TTR the SMA, which simply calculates the mean, that is a walking window of:

> Sum of gains and losses over the 14 days (assuming it's the 14 days period)

In Bloomberg this is done only for first 14 days, subsequent days are calculated as:

> [(previous average gain) x 13 + last gain] / 14

I suspect it should be enough to swap SMA with a custom moving average function. Was just wondering if such a function is already a part of TTR or is easy to implement?

Comment: I need to investigate more, but it looks like this may be a bug in `TTR::RSI`.

Comment: Reading the source of TTR, it appears an EMA is being used by default on the diffs in price, Datageek: Are you specifying SMA?

Comment: I am specifying SMA indeed. SMA however is simply "sum of gains over last x days". It doesn't use the "previous average gain x (x-1) + last gain / x" logic.

Comment: `SMA` is not the "sum of gains over last x days"; it's the mean. I don't understand why you're confused that the results are different when you specify a different moving average. I would be concerned if they were the same. The potential bug I referred to is that the positive/negative values are set to zero (instead of missing) when calculating the down/up averages, respectively.

Comment: Agree, SMA is a moving average over x days, i.e. mean. I am simply stating this RSI is not the same as what Bloomberg computes and was wondering how to calculate exactly the same results in TTR.

Comment: The default should be close, except for the issue I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich it is not very close actually. See my edit.

Comment: Of course that's not close! If you use a different moving average, why would you expect the results to be the same?  I said *the default* should be close.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich You are right! I was trying EMA, SMA, etc but they did differ. Using default parameters produces indeed the closest value.

Comment: @Datageek : How are you getting a different answer with EMA and the default?

Comment: @KyleBalkissoon The default seems to be using also maArgs$wilder parameter: 

`if (missing(maType)) {
    maType <- "EMA"
    maArgs$wilder <- TRUE
}`

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this? I have been looking at stockcharts and tradingview. It is nowhere close to RSI in TTR